# JsonObject not found

Tags: java, json

I am calling an api through the following code,

```
System.out.println("its running");
String realTimeData = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

String inputline;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(response.append(inputLine));
}
in.close();
```

where `response` outputs the following Json output.

```
{"time":{"updated":"Mar 4, 2018 18:53:00 UTC","updatedISO":"2018-03-04T18:53:00+00:00","updateduk":"Mar 4, 2018 at 18:53 GMT"},"disclaimer":"This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org","chartName":"Bitcoin","bpi":{"USD":{"code":"USD","symbol":"&#36;","rate":"11,333.4625","description":"United States Dollar","rate_float":11333.4625},"GBP":{"code":"GBP","symbol":"&pound;","rate":"8,208.4869","description":"British Pound Sterling","rate_float":8208.4869},"EUR":{"code":"EUR","symbol":"&euro;","rate":"9,200.3915","description":"Euro","rate_float":9200.3915}}}
```

I am trying to get the data through keys, using this code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
String rate = json.getString("time");
System.out.println("rate was "+rate);
```

Whenever I run the above snippet, I get a `JsonObject {"time"} not found`. My conclusion is either I don't understand what is a "key" in the above json format. or the `response` that CoinDesk spits out is not getting treated as Json in my code.

Comment: You need to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands now, we won't even know which JSON package you use. `JSONObject` is not really a seldom class name.

Comment: @lexicore it's usually `org.json` that people refer to when using `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to get the field `time` as a String. When it's not. It's a JSONObject.

Note also that you were not using the right constructor.

Here's what you should do instead:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject (response.toString ());

JSONObject oTime = json.getJSONObject ("time");

System.out.println("rate was " + oTime);
```

Comment: I feel so stupid, I was trying to get `time` as String and Integer and what not, and I didn't think of grabbing it as Json.

Comment: @Sahil glad I could help! Also, see my edit regarding the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The "time" is key for another JSONObject.
If you want retrieve USD rate from "time" object, try this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject bpi = json.getJSONObject("bpi");
JSONObject usd = bpi.getJSONOBJECT("USD");
String rate = usd.getString("rate");
System.out.println("rate was "+rate);
```

Further info: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html
You can check JSON structure easily at: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
Hope I could help you!